# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

Tags: calculus

The following is the method that I want to use.

By letting

$$u=(1+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$dx = -2u^{-3}du$$

and

$$x=u^{-2}-1$$

So ignoring the limits of integration so far, I get

$$ -2\int{ \frac{u^{-2}}{u^{-2}-1}}du$$

which can be simplified to

$$ -2 \int{ \frac{1}{1-u^{2}}}du$$

From here I did trigonometric substitution with $u=cos(\theta)$.

However, that yields an answer of form that involves $\ln |\sec(\theta) + \tan(\theta)|$ which $\theta$ is in terms of $u$ which is in terms of $x$.

I am not confident that this is a correct way to answer this question, and the fact that during the process I got something suspiciously close to

$$\int \frac{1}{1+u^2} du$$

which is very common in improper integrals give me a guts feeling that I am not going in the right direction.  Can someone help me out?  This is a problem that I have been asked by my student and I wanted some input.

Comment: Notice that the integrand is undefined for $x=0$ and for $x\le-1$.

Comment: Because the primitive function is $-2\,\operatorname{arctanh} \left( \sqrt {1+x} \right) $, the integral is undefined with this limits.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{(1-u)(1+u)}=\frac{A}{1-u}+\frac{B}{1+u}$$

And remember that, as user84413 said, the integral is improper and must be computed in the intervals $\ (-1,0) $ and $\ (0,+\infty)$

Answer (score 2):

The integral does not exist. For the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ does not exist: the integrand blows up badly near $0$. Near $x=0$ it behaves like $\frac{1}{x}$.

**Remark:** Additionally, if you wish to operate in the reals, the integrand is not defined when $x\lt -1$.